# $.post function(response) does not return successfully

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using select2 to get multiple member names in one input element. And here is my ajax code: (inside my form.php)

```
      $('#student_vgroup').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault(); 

      var name = $('#select2_demo_2').val();
      var day = $('#day_vgroup').val();
      var venue = $('#venue_vgroup').val();
      var time = $('#time_vgroup').val();

        $.post(
          'includes/vgroup-func.php',
          {
            member_name: name,
            day: day,
            venue: venue,
            time: time,
            leader_id: id
          },
          function(result){
            if (result == "success") {
              location.reload();
            } else {
                $('.error-message-vgroup').load("includes/vgroup-func.php", {
                member_name: name,
                day: day,
                venue: venue,
                time: time,
                leader_id: id
              });
            }
          }
        );
     });
```

I have this code in my server-side: (I will just write the idea because it's too long)

validation.php

```
 <?php
    $day =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['day']);
    $venue = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['venue']);
    $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time']);

    if(!isset($_POST['member_name'])) {
       echo "enter member names";
    } else {
        foreach($_POST['member_name'] as $selectedOptions) {

          *query data from database to check if one of the members selected 
           already exists in my group.
          *query data form database to check if one of the members selected is 
           my leader.
          *query data from database to check if one of the members selected 
           already belongs to someone else's group.

          if (already exists in my group) {
             echo "Cannot add. Already in your group";
          } elseif (is my leader) {
             echo "Cannot add leader";
          } elseif (belongs to someone else) {
             echo "Cannot add from someone else's group";
          } elseif (empty($day)) {
             echo "Enter day";
          } elseif (empty($venue)) {
             echo "Enter venue";
          } elseif (empty($time)) {
             echo "Enter time";
          } else {
             *insert data to the database
             echo "success";
          }
        }
    }

?>
```

My question is, the validation works just fine. But it doesn't seem to enter in the 'success' state in my ajax function(result) call. The success gets echoed out in the div tag with a class "error-message-vgroup" where my error message goes, instead of reloading the page. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Add `console.log(result);` right after `function(result){` in your js to see server response

Comment: I have seen php to add white spaces before and after. Try trimming the response string. And as mentioned by Rulisp console.log would be first step to debug. console.log("AA"+result+"AA") add stuff before and after so you know if there any spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. Now, I have put console.log(result) after my function(result), but it doesn't print anything in the console. What happens really though, that I forgot to mention, once it passes all the validation constraints, the data actually gets inserted in the database, but it doesn't reload the page. So in return, the error message which says 'Cannot add. Already in your group' gets called..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try to return your output in this way from the outside of loop.

```
$output = "";
foreach($_POST['member_name'] as $selectedOptions) {

      *query data from database to check if one of the members selected 
       already exists in my group.
      *query data form database to check if one of the members selected is 
       my leader.
      *query data from database to check if one of the members selected 
       already belongs to someone else's group.

      if (already exists in my group) {
         $output = "Cannot add. Already in your group";
      } elseif (is my leader) {
         $output ="Cannot add leader";
      } elseif (belongs to someone else) {
         $output ="Cannot add from someone else's group";
      } elseif (empty($day)) {
         $output ="Enter day";
      } elseif (empty($venue)) {
         $output ="Enter venue";
      } elseif (empty($time)) {
         $output ="Enter time";
      } else {
         *insert data to the database
         $output ="success";
      }
    }

    echo $output;
    exit;
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thanks man! I don't know why I haven't thought of that. I was so pre-occupied with dealing with this one in particular, I forgot to debug things as simple as possible.. Thanks again!

Comment: @Eric Your welcome. I really happy to know that your problem has been solved.